# Concatenate by selecting cells in multiple columns

Tags: excel, concatenation

I have a column for each of 4 variables, lets call them A,B,C,D.  Each variable has a multitude of values.
I want to select only one cell in each column and then press a button which would: 1)concatenate them and 2) place the result in column E. 
So I could select A2, B5,C3 and D1, press the magic button (maybe the magic button needs to be pressed before and after selecting the cells) and in column E I would have the concatenation of the values in: A2, B5, C3, D1  placed in column E.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which cell in column **E?**

Comment: The cell would be E1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd define a custom concatenation function in VBA, e.g.

```
Function Conc(v As Variant, Optional ByVal sDelim As String = "") As String
    Dim vLoop As Variant
    If IsArray(v) Or TypeName(v) = "Range" Then
        For Each vLoop In v
            If Conc = "" Then
                Conc = vLoop
            Else
                Conc = Conc & sDelim & vLoop
            End If
        Next vLoop
    Else
        Conc = CStr(v)
    End If
End Function
```

and then you can use it in a `Sub` to your liking, e.g.

```
Sub ConcatenateCells()
    Range("E1") = Conc(Selection)
End Sub
```

I'm saying to your liking since you didn't explain where in column E should the result be as Gary's Student pointed out. You can bind this `Sub` to a button or a shortcut like CTRL+SHIFT+C.

Comment: Got it.  I think...  Let me try to get this to work.  I'm not too good at this.  I'll send a better comment later, but thanks for such a quick response!

Answer (score 1):

Not quite what OP demands but possibly of interest to somebody else requiring a non-VBA approach (ie close if not exact):

`=`, Ctrl+ select each of the four cells in turn, Enter and then Replace `,` with `&`.